# Div está ignorando o padding do elemento pai

Tags: html, css, css-padding

Eu estou com problemas na hora de usar um div, por algum motivo ele está ignorando o padding o elemento pai.

```
<div data-v-fae5bece="" class="flex xs12 sm12 md12 lg12"><div data-v-fae5bece="" class="v-card__text baner" style="
    padding: 16px;
"><div data-v-fae5bece="">Dafadasd</div></div></div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero fazer com o **div** onde está o texto obedeça o padding

Comment: Cara só com esse pedaço de código e sem o resto do CSS não da para te responder direito. Edite sua pergunta e inclua o CSS completo e o HTML mínimo que de para simular o seu problema ai

Answer (score 1):

O Padding esta sendo feito. Acontece que seu header esta sobrepondo ele.

Faça um teste, coloque um padding maior no top: `style="padding-top: 200px;"`